# Handling docker events in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, docker, curl, docker-api

I would like to catch docker events and do something if something is happend. There are lots of ways to "get/print events":

```sh
# With curl
curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http:/v1.40/events

# With nc
echo -e "GET /events HTTP/1.0\r\n" | nc -U /var/run/docker.sock
```

But is there any way to listen continously and handle each row/event? Eg:

```sh
while EVENT ?magic?; do
    ACTION=$(echo $EVENT | jq .Action )
    if [ $ACTION -eq "start" ]; then ....; fi
done
```

---

**Solution**

After @Adiii answer, a short solution:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

function handle {
    # Check the line is a JSON line:
    if [[ ${1:0:1} == "{" ]]; then

        # ... You can do here anything ...

        # Print: "LOG $line", "LOG" is green
        echo -e "\033[32;1mLOG\033[0m $line"
    fi
}

echo -e "GET /events HTTP/1.0\r\n" | nc -U /var/run/docker.sock | while read line; do handle $line; done;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try `docker events` which continuously console docker event.

```
docker events
```

For example if you just interested to grep `container started` event the below command will work, or you can improve the below script.

```
#!/bin/bash
docker events |  while read line; do  if [[ ${line} = *"start"* ]];then echo " container started ${line}" ;fi ; done
```

Comment: Thank you, I added a short solution to my question, because I couldn't insert here.